# import c++ dll, returning a structure with array of doubles

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, dllimport

I have a dll containing a function that returns a structure with a byte, and an array of 7 doubles:

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public byte v1;     
public Blob v2;
}
```

the dll function:

```
[DllImport("myDLL", EntryPoint = "?myDLLFuntion@@YA?AUmyStruct@@XZ", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern MyStruct myDLLFunction();
```

this is my blob:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = ((sizeof(double))*7))]
public struct Blob
{
// Intentionally left empty. It's just a blob
}
```

I created a function to get the array:

```
public double[] GetArray(Blob NameBlob)
{

    IntPtr dPtr = IntPtr.Zero;  
    try
    {
        dPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(((sizeof(double))*7));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(NameBlob, dPtr, false);
        double[] r = new double[((sizeof(double))*7)];

        Marshal.Copy(dPtr, r, 0, ((sizeof(double))*7));

        return r;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dPtr != IntPtr.Zero) 
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

I called it like this:

```
myStruct s1=myDLLFunction();

GetArray(s1.v2)[0]; // print it
```

I get the wrong value, please if someone can help me that would be great, I'm stating the use of Marshal... I think there is where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: PS: I can't change the Dll, It's not mine

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just so you know, you can edit your own post, so you don't have to add comments =)

Comment: StructureToPtr() does not do anything when the structure doesn't have any fields.  You need to declare the array, use MarshalAs to declare it a ByvalArray.

Comment: Plz Hans can you give me an exemple of what you're saying I couldn't understand what your trying to exmplain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out, `StructureToPtr()` doesn't do anything when the struct doesn't have any fields.  I think we was talking about this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Blob
{
    [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    double[] array;
}
```